# Gauss-Seidel method to compute 3 systems of linear equations

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

My assignment to develop a program to compute 3 systems of linear equations:  the program must allow the user to input the coefficients and constants, number of iterations and level of acceptable error.  I can't seem to include both the number of iterations and level of error as parameters to stop the loop and show the final values of the variables.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Welcome. This is  Problem 1. "<<endl;
    cout<<"computing systems of  three linear equations through gauss-seidel method"<<endl;

    float coefEqxn1[3];
    for (int x=0; x<3;)
    {
        for ( int eq1=1; eq1<=3; eq1++)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter Coefficient " <<eq1<< " of equation 1 : ";
            cin>>coefEqxn1[x];
            x++;
        }
    }

    float coefEqxn2[3];
    for (int x=0; x<3;)
    {
        for ( int eq2=1; eq2<=3; eq2++)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter Coefficient " <<eq2<<" of equation 2 :" ;
            cin>>coefEqxn2[x];
            x++;
        }
    }

    float coefEqxn3[3];
    for (int x=0; x<3;)
    {
        for ( int eq3=1; eq3<=3; eq3++)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter Coefficient "<<eq3<<" of equation 3 :";
            cin>>coefEqxn3[x];
            x++;
        }
    }

    float constants[3];
    for (int y=0; y<3;)
    {
        for (int con=1; con<=3; con++)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter the contant of equation "<<con<<" : ";
            cin>>constants[y];
            y++;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Calculating through Cramer's Rule..."<<endl;

    int iteration=0;
    cout<<"enter # iteration"<<endl;
    cin>>iteration;

    int stopC=0;
    cout<<"enter level of error"<<endl;
    cin>>stopC;

    float matrixArray[3][4];
    {
        for ( int y=0; y<3;)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<=3;x++)
                matrixArray[0][y]=coefEqxn1[y];
            y++;
        }

        matrixArray[0][3]=constants[0];

        for ( int y=0; y<3;)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<=3;x++)
                matrixArray[1][y]=coefEqxn2[y];
            y++;
        }

        matrixArray[1][3]=constants[1];
        for ( int y=0; y<3;)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<=3;x++)
                matrixArray[2][y]=coefEqxn3[y];
            y++;
        }

        matrixArray[2][3]=constants[2];
    }

    for(int a=0; a<3; a++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<=3; b++)
            cout<<"matrixArray["<<a<<"]["<<b<<"]: "<<matrixArray[a][b]<<endl;   
    }

    float valueOfX[100], valueOfY[100], valueOfZ[100];

    for( int i=1; i<iteration; )
    {
        valueOfX[0]=0, valueOfY[0]=0, valueOfZ[0]=0;

        valueOfX[i]=(matrixArray[0][3]-(matrixArray[0][2]*valueOfZ[i-1]+matrixArray[0][1]*valueOfY[i-1]))/matrixArray[0][0];
        valueOfY[i]=(matrixArray[1][3]-(matrixArray[1][2]*valueOfZ[i-1]+matrixArray[1][0]*valueOfX[i]))/matrixArray[1][1];
        valueOfZ[i]=(matrixArray[2][3]-(matrixArray[2][1]*valueOfY[i]+matrixArray[2][0]*valueOfX[i]))/matrixArray[2][2];

        float reX=0, reY=0, reZ=0;

        reX=((valueOfX[i+1]-valueOfX[i])/valueOfX[i+1])*100;
        reY=((valueOfY[i+1]-valueOfY[i])/valueOfY[i+1])*100;
        reX=((valueOfZ[i+1]-valueOfZ[i])/valueOfZ[i+1])*100;

        if (reX<=inputErrorLevel)
            break;

        if (reY<=inputErrorLevel)
            break;

        if (reZ<=inputErrorLevel)
            break;

        cout<<"reX = "<<reX<<endl;
        cout<<"reY = "<<reY<<endl;
        cout<<"reY = "<<reX<<endl;

        i++;
    }

    cout<<"x = "<<valueOfX[iteration-1]<<endl;
    cout<<"y = "<<valueOfY[iteration-1]<<endl;
    cout<<"z = "<<valueOfZ[iteration-1]<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want you should have something like

```
double inputErrorLevel; //Read from user input

// The for loop guarantees that the loop will run at max iteration times.
// Noticed I changed it to start from zero otherwise it will only run
// iteration -1 times 
for( int i=0; i<iteration; ++i )
{

  //Do heavy computation stuff.

  double currentErrorLevel = ComputeErrorAtCurrentIteration();
  if ( currentErrorLevel < inputErrorLevel )
       break; // break will ensure more iterations are not done
              // if error level is acceptable
}
```

Typical programming practice is to to

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5; ++i )
{
}
```

instead of

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5; )
{
 ++i;
}
```

Comment: there are three variables so i have to compute for each?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typo?

```
reX=((valueOfZ[i+1]-valueOfZ[i])/valueOfZ[i+1])*100;
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
reZ=((valueOfZ[i+1]-valueOfZ[i])/valueOfZ[i+1])*100;
```

Same here:

```
cout<<"reY = "<<reX<<endl;
```

But to answer your question this should be using i to index the results not iteration. iteration variable is going to always be constant so it will always give that result regardless of error.

Like:

```
cout<<"x = "<<valueOfX[i-1]<<endl;
cout<<"y = "<<valueOfY[i-1]<<endl;
cout<<"z = "<<valueOfZ[i-1]<<endl;
```